# CakePHP - Trouble extending __construct function

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm currently trying to extend the BaseAuthenticate class within CakepPHP (in the `cake\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\Auth` folder) via the FormAuthenticate class and I'm having trouble extending the construct function.

I'm trying to extend the construct function to declare a new object that can then be used throughout the class.

```
//BaseAuthenticate.php

public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings) {
    $this->_Collection = $collection;
    $this->settings = Hash::merge($this->settings, $settings);
}

//ExtendedFormAuthenticate.php

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings);
}
```

If I use the above __construct in ExtendedFormAuthenticate.php I get the error message `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
}
```

If I use the above __construct in ExtendedFormAuthenticate.php I get `undefined variable` error messages because I'm not populating those variables, but I don't know what to populate them with.

Does anyone know how I can successfully extend the BaseAuthenticate.php construct function? Or alternatively, does anyone know how to declare an object to be used within a class without it being in the __construct function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings);
}
```

to this:

```
public function __construct(ComponentCollection $collection, $settings)
{
    parent::__construct($collection, $settings);
}
```